# how to disable b-table header sort function and sort column by custom sort

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have a b-table and a multiple  Drop-down menu and When I choose two options,

I want the b-table to be sorted according to the two options I selected.

For example, if Date and Time are selected, they are sorted according to Date + Time string.

I don't know if the b-table can do this function or need to user origin table to do this question